# IOS: How to create a Master View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I started a project with storyboards and it has a lot of views, each one of them has the same header (with an image, company name and two buttons). I want to do this once in the main View, and make it reusable for the other views. It’s like a master view with a header and footer. How could i do this?

This is my first project starting from cero and I want to make it as organized as possible. What are the best practices using storyboards and MVC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special way of doing this in storyboard.

But you can do it easily by making custom `UIView`.

Make a sub class of `UIView` and pust all common design in it.

Place a `UIView` on top of every `UIViewController.UIView`.
Now set this top `UIView's` class with your custom class in identity inspector.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

A primitive way to do it in storyboard is to define there your master view, select all of its elements, copy them and paste them into the other views.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIViewController to add a header to its view, and UITableViewController to set it as the tableview header.